# How to open single calendar event via URL from OWA

Tags: office365, outlook-web-app

When I open a specific calendar event in Outlook Web App by clicking on its "Open in Separate Window" button, the calendar event opens in a popup with its URL in the address bar. In this case: `https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#viewmodel=_d.$l6&wid=18&ispopout=1`

[image]

But when I try to open this link from a blank browser tab, it will hang  on the OWA loading screen.

How can I alter or reverse engineer this link to open the specific calendar event from any tab?

Comment: Are you authenticated on the blank browser tab? i.e. is an office365 session active in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I am authenticated with an active Office 365 session

Comment: If you're authenticated, ideally you should not need to do any reverse engineering, it should just work by pasting the link in any number of tabs if the session is active. Does the URL change when you paste it in a new tab? If it does, can you put both URLs in the question?

Comment: No, it stays exactly the same

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I am looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The popup is managed within OWA JavaScript of the **parent** window, referenced by the wid=18 and not intended to be exposed.  Therefore the window can not stand by itself.  You can see this also if you refresh the parent window (or logoff/logon), and then try to use this pop-out window, it will fail because the link is broken to the parent.